# Why is a 3-D sphere/cube centered at the origin not a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My class notes states that: a 3-D cube or sphere centered at the origin is not a subspace as it is not closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Why is this the case? I am having trouble understanding how it is not closed under addition.

Comment: What do you know about the "closed under addition" condition?

Comment: There are three conditions to a subspace: 1) the zero vector of subspace V must be in a subset W. 2) for many x, y in W then x+y is in W as well 3) for any x in subset W then a scalar multiple times x is in subset W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that this cube is the unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$ centered around the origin. Notice, $(0,1)$ is a vector in the unit cube, but a scalar of such a vector, e.g $(0,2)$, is not in the cube. Hence, it is not closed under scalar multiplication.

Take a vector $(1,0)$ and add it to a vector $(0,1)$. The resulting vector is $(1,1)$ which is not in the unit cube (since it has a length of $\sqrt{2}$). Thus, your cube is not closed under addition.